# ERRORLEVEL cannot report regsvr32's process exit code, why?

Tags: cmd

On Windows 7 SP1, from CMD window, run command `regsvr32 none.dll`, regsvr32 will fail with exit code 3. This is the expected behavior of regsvr32, as stated in [Raymond Chen's blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180920-00/?p=99785).

Procmon verifies this as well.

However, when checking regsvr32's exit code with `echo %ERRORLEVEL%`, I got zero. WHY?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no exit code available because you are typing, so A. This is not a programming question B See `start /?` and the part that says _When executing an application that is a 32-bit GUI application, CMD.EXE does not wait for the application to terminate before returning to the command prompt.  This new behavior does NOT occur if executing  within a command script_

Comment: `%errorlevel%` is also cleared at the end of every line when typing.

Comment: There seems to be an obscure rule about "when ERRORLEVEL will change". In my case today, If CMD command line launches the GUI program `regsvr32` successfully(=CreateProcess succesfulyy, regardless of whether regsvr32 exit successfully), the ERRORLEVEL will not change(no matter whether it was 0 or something else).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Marks comment. I was just tripped by CMD's sneaky behavior.

To know the exit code of a GUI process like `regsvr32`, the CMD command line has to be:

```
start /wait regsvr32.exe none.dll
```

What is special about `regsvr32` is: If we run `regsvr /s xxx.dll` , `/s` makes regsvr totally silent, looking very much like a CUI program. So users are more easily get trapped.

But if we execute `regsvr32 none.dll` inside a `.bat`/`.cmd` batch script, `start /wait` is not required. Such discrepancy (on command prompt vs inside batch script) often causes trouble for the unwary. Sigh.

Comment: Note old behaviour in help is the OS/2 CMD.exe which was ported to NT and was written by an IBM engineer. I think she did a psycho job. New behaviour is CMD updated by Microsoft programmers. Note also the change in titles. She, long ago, was an ENGINEER. Now the people are programmers and not engineers usually (PLCs are nearly always programmed by engineers).